# Detect ctrl+click on button in pygtk

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I want to detect if ctrl is held down when the user clicks a button.  The 'clicked' signal doesn't seem to pass enough information to the callback to work this out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can connect to either [`button-press-event`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.24/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--button-press-event) or [`button-release-event`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.24/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--button-release-event) instead of `clicked`, the `event` passed to the callback can be used to get the modifier state (using [`get_state`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.24/class-gdkevent.html#method-gdkevent--get-state)) and check if control key is pressed. For ex.

```
def button_release_callback(widget, event, data=None):
    if event.get_state() &  gtk.gdk.CONTROL_MASK:
        print "Ctrl held"
    else:
        print "Ctrl not held"
...
button.connect("button-release-event", button_release_callback)
```

Hope this helps!