# Detecting a Ctrl+click event in lablgtk

Tags: gtk, mouseevent, ocaml, lablgtk

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371968) explains how to detect a ctrl+click in pygtk.

Does it also work on Lablgtk? Or is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lablgtk, there is a more direct solution, although it is not immediately obvious.

From a mouse click event `ev` (of type `GdkEvent.Button.t`), you can detect events such as ctrl+click/shift+click with `GdkEvent.Button.state` and `Gdk.Convert.modifier`), as in the following example:

```
let state = GdkEvent.Button.state ev in
let modifiers = Gdk.Convert.modifier state in
let button = GdkEvent.Button.button ev in
if button = 1 && List.mem `CONTROL modifiers then
  (* Ctrl+left click *) ...
else if button = 3 && List.mem `SHIFT` modifiers then
  (* Shift+right click *) ...
```

The type of the modifier list is `Gdk.Tags.modifier`.